# Postico & Postgres error - could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the latest macOS Catalina.

I've looked into other threads but not sure how to solve mine because I have two errors on both Postgres and Postico.

Postgres says I have a `Stale postmaster.pid file`

Postico says

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I went on Youtube for a solution to address the stale postmaster.pid file, and deleted it using the terminal... but the error still persists..

Should I uninstall, and reinstall Postgres and Postico?

Comment: What is the connection string you are using? Have you tried restarting the Postgres server?  What is the ```port``` set to in postgresql.conf?  FYI, deleting the postmaster.pid without verifying the server is not running is a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the terminal to delete `postmaster.pid` didn't do it for some reason. I had to do it via Finder manually.

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Postico.
I just reinstalled Postgres.app and initialize again my data base on the app, and after go back on Postico.